# Get columns and types for all tables

Tags: sql-server

I need to get all the table names and column types from `sys.columns`. I tried this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_ID 
FROM   sys.COLUMNS
```

But `OBJECT_ID` gives the value and not the exact name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`object_name()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186301.aspx) function to get the name of an object from a given `object_id`.

And you can join onto [`sys.types`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188021.aspx) view to get the type name:

```
select c.object_id, object_name(c.object_id), c.name, t.name from sys.columns c
join sys.types t on t.system_type_id = c.system_type_id;
```

Comment: @AaronBertrand Which `name`, I've just made a few ninja-edits?

Comment: `t.name` which wasn't there originally. Thanks. Schema name is often useful too, since you could have `dbo.authors` and `foo.authors`. Also the user asked for data types...

Comment: Sorry about all the hassle, but `c.name` should be in there too, right? I'm not sure how useful the `object_id` is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it could help

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID 
ORDER BY schema_name, table_name;
```